# In play 2.3.x, differing failures with both ebean and jpa

Tags: java, jpa, ebean, playframework-2.3

I am having database woes.  In the controller below I am trying to toggle a boolean on a record with a passed-in ID.  When I use ebean syntax I can query, insert, and delete but not update.  It's as if I am unable to commit my transactions on updates but they get auto-committed with the other operations.  When I use JPA syntax it appears that I am interacting with an in-memory database rather than the configured postgresql.  I say that because when I query I get null back.  But if I insert a record using JPA I will subsequently be able to query and update it successfully.  But those updates do not appear in postgres plus the only fields that are set on the record I have queried are the id and the boolean flag.

Here is my code and config.  Thank you!

from build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  javaJpa,
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "4.3.6.Final",
  "play2-crud" %% "play2-crud" % "0.7.4-SNAPSHOT",
  cache,
  javaWs,
  "javax.mail" % "javax.mail-api" % "1.5.2",
  "javax.activation" % "activation" % "1.1.1",
  "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901-1.jdbc4"
)
```

from application.conf

```
# Database configuration
# ~~~~~
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="postgres://username:password@localhost/playdb"
db.default.autocommit=true

# You can expose this datasource via JNDI if needed (Useful for JPA)
db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS

jpa.default=defaultPersistenceUnit

# Ebean configuration
# ~~~~~
ebean.default="models.*"
```

from persistence.xml

org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence
    DefaultDS

and from my controller

```
// JPA style
@Transactional
public static Result toggleMailboxJpa(Long mailbox)
{
    // does not update
    MailboxConfig x = JPA.em().find(MailboxConfig.class, mailbox);
    x.suspended = !x.suspended;

    // transactional appears to work, these have no effect
    JPA.em().persist(x);
    JPA.em().flush();

    return redirect("/admin/mailboxStatus");
}

@Transactional
public static Result toggleMailboxEbean(Long mailbox)
{
    MailboxConfig x = MailboxConfig.find.byId(mailbox);
    x.suspended = !x.suspended;
    x.update();

    // this syntax has the same effect (reads from the db fine but does not commit)
    /*
    MailboxConfig x = Ebean.find(MailboxConfig.class).where().eq("id", mailbox).findUnique();
    x.suspended = !x.suspended;
    Ebean.save(x);
    */

    return redirect("/admin/mailboxStatus");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
x.update(mailbox)
```

with "mailbox" the id